# Is there anything wrong to check the identity of the matrix?

Tags: c, loops

I've got a question to check if the input matrix is an identity matrix. I don't know why I can't get the proper check with my own program and I do not get any syntax error. I think I've got logical error but I can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
  int a[MAX][MAX];
  int n, error=0, i=0, j=0;
  do
    {
      printf("The size of the matrix you want to check: \n");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      if(n<1)
    printf("Your number is invalid\n");
    }while(n<1);
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
    printf("a[%d][%d]= ", i+1, j+1);
    do
      {
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        if(isdigit(a[i][j]))
          printf("Yo number is invalid\n");
      }while(isdigit(a[i][j]));
      }
  }
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
    if(i=j)
      if(a[i][j]!=1)
        error=1;
      else
       if(a[i][j]!=0)
        error=1;
      }
    }
  if(error==1)
    printf("This matrix is not an identity\n");
  else
    printf("This matrix is is an indentity\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ALWAYS** enable compile warnings.

Your code gives the following compile-warnings:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’ [-Wparentheses]
```

**The first warning** is because you use `=` which is assignment operator. The compiler I tried on suggested using parentheses which isn't actually what you need. But, at least, the compiler pointed you to a problem where you use assignment as a truth value.
Surely, the compiler wouldn't know if you really want to know it as a truth value or you just used `=` by mistake instead of `==`. But **you know** that you meant comparison not assignment.

**The second warning** is on the following segment of the program:

```c
if(i==j)
  if(a[i][j]!=1)
    error=1;
  else
   if(a[i][j]!=0)
    error=1;
```

You should add braces to be clear on which if the else statement belongs to. C compilers don't infer that by indentation. So, both of the following segments will be identical:

```c
if(i==j)
    if(a[i][j]!=1)
        error=1;
    else
        if(a[i][j]!=0)
            error=1;
```

```c
if(i==j)
    if(a[i][j]!=1)
        error=1;
else
    if(a[i][j]!=0)
        error=1;
```

You need to add curly braces to be clear. I also think you've a logical-error. Like the following:

```c
if(i==j)
{
    if(a[i][j]!=1)
        error=1;
}
else
{
    if(a[i][j]!=0)
        error=1;
}
```

See how more cleaner, readable, and free of compile-warnings is this ?

---

There is another thing that caught my eyes, which is your usage of `isdigit`. Your usage of `isdigit` is totally wrong. This function takes an int which represents an ASCII code, and it returns a positive integer if thie ASCII code represents a digit; returns 0 otherwise. You actually don't pass an ASCII code (char variable). The variable is already of type `int` and that's it. You don't need to do any checks against it.

Another thing that's not much important, is to improve performance a little bit but breaking the loops when `error` variable is set to 1.

You don't need to continue the loop if you already known it's not identity matrix.

Comment: I don't know why but I don't have any warning at all. Maybe my gcc don't have such a good quality as yours. Which compiler have you been using?

Comment: @HoangNam, I'm using GCC. Did you enable `-Wall` compiler flag ?

Comment: How can I enable it? I'm now using gcc on ubuntu

Comment: @HoangNam, I think `gcc -Wall main.c` would do the trick. I've also updated the answer with some additional notes.

Comment: I got your additional information. That's really useful and makes my program much better now

Answer (score -1):

If you notice  `if(i=j)` is not a comparison but assignment. Update with `if(i==j)` for comparison